# How to do a HTTP POST request in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, http-post

I'm trying to do a POST request in an android studio like this.

```
 btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            //submitForm();
            tryLogin("test@test.com", "Test1234");
        }
    });





protected void tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
 {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter request = null;

    URL url = null;
    String response = null;
    String parameters = "email="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try
    {
        url = new URL("URL");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();
        String line = "";
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.
        response = sb.toString();
        // You can perform UI operations here
        Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();
        isr.close();
        reader.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        // Error
    }
```

But the app crashes and I get an error like this -

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: test, PID: 19928
>
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at 
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:>1425)
>
> at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)

I have added internet permission in the manifest file.
Is this because I have not done it via AsyncTask? 
How can I fix this?

Comment: use AsyncTask .....

Comment: You can't perform network operations on main thread.. so you have to use asynctask

Comment: use separate thread for network operation. asynctask is easy in this case

Comment: it's recomended to use networking library such us [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp), [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit) or [volley](https://github.com/google/volley). It's easier to do network operation with networking library

Comment: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  **Add this 2 line before Try Block

Answer (score -1):

you can put your network operation in this thread or use asynctask or any other library

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run(){        
            txt1.setText("Thread!!");
            }
        }).start();
```